# Update multiple rows from results from a SELECT query to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to combine these two queries.

```
SELECT `o`.`Order_ID`
FROM `Orders` `o`
JOIN `CustomerDetails` `cd` ON `cd`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`
WHERE `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
AND `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` <= '2013-06-31 23:59:59'
AND `cd`.`SalesRep_ID` = 6
```

This gives me a list of `Order_ID`s that I need to update with the `SalesRep_ID = 6` from the above Query.

After I get the list of `Order_ID`s from the Query above I use...

```
UPDATE Orders SET SalesRep_ID =  '6'
WHERE  (Order_ID = 541304
OR  Order_ID = 541597
OR  Order_ID = 542318)
```

Doing so updates the orders with the correct `SalesRep_ID`.

Ultimately I'd like to combine these to make one query where I would just change the `SalesRep_ID`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with proper `UPDATE` syntax with `JOIN` for MySql

```
UPDATE Orders o JOIN CustomerDetails d 
    ON d.Customer_ID = o.Customer_ID
   SET o.SalesRep_ID = 6
 WHERE o.OrderPlaceServerTime >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
   AND o.OrderPlaceServerTime <= '2013-06-31 23:59:59'
   AND d.SalesRep_ID = 6
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc24b/1)** demo

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single query by just simply combining them:

```
UPDATE Orders SET SalesRep_ID =  '6'
WHERE Order_ID IN (
   SELECT `o`.`Order_ID`
   FROM `Orders` `o`
   JOIN `CustomerDetails` `cd` ON `cd`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`
   WHERE `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
      AND `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` <= '2013-06-31 23:59:59'
      AND `cd`.`SalesRep_ID` = 6
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little trick to this.  You have to fool MySQL into thinking that you are working on different tables.

```
UPDATE Orders SET SalesRep_ID =  '6'
WHERE  (Order_ID IN (SELECT order_id FROM (SELECT `o`.`Order_ID`
FROM `Orders` `o`
JOIN `CustomerDetails` `cd` ON `cd`.`Customer_ID` = `o`.`Customer_ID`
WHERE `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
AND `o`.`OrderPlaceServerTime` <= '2013-06-31 23:59:59'
AND `cd`.`SalesRep_ID` = 6) AS TEMP));
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1e32/1)